# How to delete an object store in indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I can't find in the documentation any information about deleting an object store from IndexedDB. I don't want to delete a record in the store, or the database itself, but an object store. Is there such a possibility?

Comment: From code or just for given page ? if for given page go to Application tab in chrome dev tools.

Comment: From code. From dev tools you can delete database or clean storages, but can't delete storage

Comment: Are you referring to an object store? There is nothing in indexedDB called "object storage".

Comment: Sorry, I meant the object store, I made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation on how to delete an object store:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/deleteObjectStore

Comment: This is correct if you want to delete the object store from the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/clear

First, you need to create a transaction to IndexedDB instance specifying the access options to the table. Since you want to manipulate, set: **"readwrite"** option for `mode: IDBTransactionMode`, then the name of the table you want to drop, in my case its called *"photos_os"*.

```js
function dropTable() {
    const objectStore = db.transaction('photos_os', "readwrite").objectStore('photos_os');
    const objectStoreRequest = objectStore.clear();

    objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
        console.log('Erase of database completed.');
    };
}
```

Comment: `objectStore.clear()` deletes all the data out of an object store, but does not delete the object store itself. Use `deleteObjectStore` to delete an object store.